# ESLint: prevent from being linted non-standard files extensions

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

My `.estintrc.yaml`:

```yaml
parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
parserOptions:
  sourceType: module
  project: tsconfig.json
  tsconfigRootDir: ./

env:
  es6: true
  browser: true
  node: true
  mocha: true

plugins:
  - "@typescript-eslint"
```

With it, I have many errors like:

```
D:\*****\project\package.json
  0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: package.json.
The extension for the file (.json) is non-standard. You should add "parserOptions.extraFileExtensions" to your config
```

I did not ask to check `.json` files.
I want `.ts` and `.vue` files only will be being linted.
Which setting I missed?

Comment: Could you fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you call eslint you can use the `—ext` flag to tell it what file types to check. To limit file types in the config file, you would have to wrap all rules and extended configs within an `override`.

I would however also recommend `eslint-plugin-json` as alternate solution.